# Wrong behaviour responsive background images

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, responsive

It's my first time making a schoolproject where I need to make my website responsive. I'm following "mobile first". On stackoverflow, I copied a good way of making background images responsive:

`background-image: url(./assets/img/bg-blue-sm.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;`

however, they're acting really weird when I bigger the screen size. How can I fix this? You can see the behaviour here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVk9T.jpg

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: var(--beige);
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: var(--pink);
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

.navigatie {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Abrade Heavy';
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url(./assets/img/nav-sm.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;

  padding: 1rem .5rem;
}

.navigatie li:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: -2rem;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  color: var(--beige);
}

.header {
  background-image: url(./assets/img/header-bg-sm.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40rem;
  padding-top: 8rem;
  margin-top: -7rem;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.date {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 10rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.date-txt {
  font-family: 'Abrade Heavy';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.intro-article {
  background-image: url(./assets/img/bg-blue-sm.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 40rem;
  margin-top: -11rem;
  padding-top: 8rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
            <ul class="navigatie">
              <li><a href=""><img src="./assets/img/logo-sm.png" alt=""></a></li>
              <li><a href="">programmatie</a></li>
              <li>
                  <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
                      <div class="bar1"></div>
                      <div class="bar2"></div>
                      <div class="bar3"></div>
                    </div>
              </li>
            </ul>

              <div class="header">
                  <h1 class="hide">INTERNATIONAAL STRAATTHEATER</h1>
                  <img src="./assets/img/titel.png" alt="IBS header background">

                  <div class="date">
                      <p class="date-txt">alle ogen gericht op</p>
                      <img src="./assets/img/datums-sm.png" alt="VRIJ 24/08 ZAT 25/08 ZO 26/08">
                  </div>
              </div>
          </header>

          <main>
            <article class="intro-article">
              <h2 class="hide">een wereld vol fantasie</h2>
              <img src="./assets/img/wereld-sm.png" alt="Een wereld vol fantasie">
              <p class="intro-txt">Een arsenaal aan gekke wezens of vriendelijke gastheren nodigen u nu al uit op een weekend vol verwondering en bewondering. Een combinatie van walking acts en tentoonstellingen zorgen voor een onvergetelijke ervaring.</p>
            </article>
          </main>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the way `cover` works.

> cover tells the browser to make sure the image always covers the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or **cut** a little bit off one of the edges. - [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/#article-header-id-0)

In your case when you widen the screen, the image tries to cover the whole width by cutting from the height.

Check the link I provided for the other values of `background-size` property to find the value that suits your need.